# How to put Selenium window into a HTML div?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently, Selenium is opening a new maximized window `driver.maximize_window()`. 
Is it possible to to open selenium window inside html div `<div id="SeleniumDiv">`(Inside already opened web browser)?
The reason for this is that I would like to have a look at the running script in my main window

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = self.driver
driver.get('some_url')
driver.maximize_window()
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="SeleniumDiv">
   #Here my selenium browser
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you able to initiate a child _browser_ embedded within another parent _browser_ manually?

Comment: Do you want to open selenium in another terminal so you can see the code running in the main window?

Comment: I have small project in Django, In certain point it uses Selenium(it runs on button click) I would like not to open new window but also I would like to seewhat selenium is doing. So I would like to put selenium my html code between div